# TSQL transform row values into one column table

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, unpivot

### Source Table

```
Col1  |Col2  |Col3  |Col4  | Col5
----------------------------------
 hi   | this | is   | a    | test
```

Destination Table

```
RowValues|
----------
hi
this
is
a
test
```

I am using Dynamic SQL.
Any help ?

This is my code , just change table name and the Id in the where clause to what suits you

```
DECLARE @sql nVARCHAR(max), @TableName  nvarchar(100), @where nvarchar(max)
set @TableName = 'stockItems'

set @where= ' where id = 2'
select @sql  ='Select '
select  @sql = @sql+  + ' '''+ [name] +' = ''+ cast(' + [name]  + ' as nvarchar(10)) as '+[name]+',  ' 
         from sys.columns where object_name (object_id) = @TableName


set @sql = stuff(@sql, len(@sql), 1, '')  +  ' From '+@TableName+ @where
print @sql
set @sql = REPLACE(@sql,',   From',' From')
set @sql = @sql + '  '
print @sql
exec(@sql)
```

Now I need to create a new table that has one column that hold holds each value as a row

Thanks to @Mahmoud-Gamal
The solution should be something like below

```
declare @cols nvarchar(max)
select @cols = STUFF((SELECT distinct ',' +
                        QUOTENAME(column_name)
                      FROM information_schema.columns
                      WHERE table_name = 'vehicles' 
                      FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
                     ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
                        , 1, 1, '');
declare @statement nvarchar(max)
set @statement ='
SELECT
    ColumnName,  Value
FROM
    Vehicles
UNPIVOT
    (
    Value
    FOR ColumnName
    IN
        (
        '+@cols+'
        )
    )
    AS A'

    execute(@statement)
```

Please change the "vehicle" table name to any table on your database that has columns from different types (datetime, int and nvarchar) and the below error is shown
Any help ?
**The type of column "Description" conflicts with the type of other columns specified in the UNPIVOT list.**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the [`UNPIVOT`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) table operator:

```
SELECT col AS RowValues
FROM table1 AS t
UNPIVOT
(
  col
  FOR value IN([col1], 
               [col2], 
               [col3],
              [col4],
              [col5])
) AS u;
```

- [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/74c9f/3)

This will give you:

```
| ROWVALUES |
|-----------|
|        hi |
|      this |
|        is |
|         a |
|      test |
```

---

### Update:

In case you don't know the names of the columns, and you want to do this dynamically, you have to do this using dynamic SQL.

But the problem is how to get the columns names?

You can get the columns names from the `information_schema.columns`, then concatenate them in one sql, then replace the columns' names in the `UNPIVOT` with this string, and execute that statement dynamically like this:

```
DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX);
DECLARE @query AS NVARCHAR(MAX);

select @cols = STUFF((SELECT distinct ',' +
                        QUOTENAME(column_name)
                      FROM information_schema.columns
                      WHERE table_name = 'Table1'
                      FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
                     ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
                        , 1, 1, '');

SELECT @query = ' SELECT col AS RowValues
                  FROM table1 AS t
                  UNPIVOT
                  (
                  val
                  FOR col IN ( ' + @cols + ' )
                  ) AS u;';

EXECUTE(@query);
```

- [**Updated SQL Fiddle Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/74c9f/7)

Comment: I don't know the columns names ! Please check my code, I have edited the question

Comment: Thanks for your reply I am using unpivot now however I can't seem to convert all the columns to a specific type . I am getting the following error:
The type of column "Id" conflicts with the type of other columns specified in the UNPIVOT list.

Comment: @JamesDayeh Where is the `ID` I can't see it, Convert it to a the same type of the other columns `varchar` for example : `CAST(Id AS VARCHAR(50))`

Comment: @JamesDayeh - As I said, you have to cast all the columns to the same data type, see [this updated sql fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/8ea90/3)

Comment: @JamesDayeh - If you want only the columns' names, why not just doing: `SELECT distinct  QUOTENAME(column_name)
FROM information_schema.columns
WHERE table_name = 'Vehicles'` like in [**this fiddle demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/8ea90/6)

Comment: I don't know the columns names. I am intending to replace the the 'Vehicles' table with @tableName. The example in the JS fiddle shows col1,col2 (where the conversion is happening). I am making it generic. Any idea how to do the conversion without knowing the column names ?

Comment: @JamesDayeh - If you are looking for only the columns' names from this, why not just using the query `SELECT distinct QUOTENAME(column_name) FROM information_schema.columns WHERE table_name = 'Vehicles'` directly? and replace the `table_name` with the variable each time?

Comment: pretty odd here, do you have team viewer so I can explain ?

Comment: @JamesDayeh - Yes, I have

Comment: user 612 352 332 
pass 6873

Comment: @JamesDayeh - I solved that problem, by making a dynamic sql statement to write the conversion for all the columns dynamically, see [this updated sql fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/984ed1/13), try it and let me know, this sql statement is with the name `@selectedcols` in that demo

Comment: Marvelous (y) Thank you very much Mahmoud. :D:D:D:D

Comment: @JamesDayeh - You're welcome any time :) If you need anything else any time, don't hesitate to ask, good luck :) And remove the team viewer username and password comment, so that no body see it :)

Answer (score 0):

I believe you want this

```
Select Col1 + Col2 + Col3 + Col4 + Col5 From Table
```

Or may be following

```
Select Col1 From Table1
 union Select Col2 From Table1 
 union Select Col3 From Table1
 union Select Col4 From Table1 
 union Select Col5 From Table1 ;
```

Comment: so you got answer right ? if yes then please post it in ANSWER section and ACCEPT it